# Spark DataFrame Filter using Binary (Array[Bytes]) data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, uuid

I have a DataFrame from a JDBC table hitting MySql and I need to filter it using a UUID. The data is stored in MySql using binary(16) and when querying out in spark is converted to Array[Byte] as expected.

I'm new to spark and have been trying various ways to pass a variable of type UUID into the DataFrame's filter method. 
Ive tried statements like

```
val id: UUID = // other logic that looks this up
df.filter(s"id = $id")
df.filter("id = " convertToByteArray(id))
df.filter("id = " convertToHexString(id))
```

All of these error with different messages. 
I just need to somehow pass in Binary types but can't seem to put my finger on how to do so properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing even more sources online, I found a way to accomplish this without using the filter method.

When I'm reading from my sparkSession, I just use an adhoc table instead of table name, as follows:

```
sparkSession.read.jdbc(connectionString, s"(SELECT id, {other col omitted) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 0x$id) AS MyTable", props)
```

This pre-filters the results for me and then I just work with the data frame as I need.

If anyone knows of a solution using filter, I'd still love to know it as that would be useful in some cases.